# How to organize containers if they use each other?

Tags: python, django, dependency-injection, architecture, containers

I use the dependency injection method in my Django web-application. I have a `containers.py` file with 3 instances of `containers.DeclarativeContainer`: BoardContainer, ColumnContainer and LabelContainer. Each of containers has repository layer, service layer and interactor layer.

```
class BoardContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    repository = providers.Factory(BoardRepository, converter=ConvertorsContainer.from_queryset_to_dto)
    service = providers.Factory(BoardService, repository=repository)
    interactor = providers.Factory(BoardInteractor, service=service)


class ColumnContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    repository = providers.Factory(ColumnRepository, converter=ConvertorsContainer.from_queryset_to_dto)
    service = providers.Factory(ColumnService, repository=repository)
    interactor = providers.Factory(ColumnInteractor, service=service, board_service=BoardContainer.service)


class LabelContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    repository = providers.Factory(LabelRepository, converter=ConvertorsContainer.from_queryset_to_dto)
    service = providers.Factory(LabelService, repository=repository)
    interactor = providers.Factory(LabelInteractor, service=service, board_service=BoardContainer.service)
```

But i need to use `LabelContainer.service` and `ColumnContainer.service` in `BoardContainer.interactor`. And it turns out that a two-way dependency is created.

---

So far I have solved this problem in this definitely a bad way:

```
class ColumnContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    repository = providers.Factory(ColumnRepository, converter=ConvertorsContainer.from_queryset_to_dto)
    service = providers.Factory(ColumnService, repository=repository)
    interactor = providers.Factory(ColumnInteractor, service=service)  # without board_service 


class LabelContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    repository = providers.Factory(LabelRepository, converter=ConvertorsContainer.from_queryset_to_dto)
    service = providers.Factory(LabelService, repository=repository)
    interactor = providers.Factory(LabelInteractor, service=service)  # without board_service


class BoardContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    repository = providers.Factory(BoardRepository, converter=ConvertorsContainer.from_queryset_to_dto)
    service = providers.Factory(BoardService, repository=repository)
    interactor = providers.Factory(BoardInteractor, service=service, column_service=ColumnContainer.service,
                                   label_service=LabelContainer.service)


class ColumnContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    repository = providers.Factory(ColumnRepository, converter=ConvertorsContainer.from_queryset_to_dto)
    service = providers.Factory(ColumnService, repository=repository)
    interactor = providers.Factory(ColumnInteractor, service=service, board_service=BoardContainer.service)


class LabelContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    repository = providers.Factory(LabelRepository, converter=ConvertorsContainer.from_queryset_to_dto)
    service = providers.Factory(LabelService, repository=repository)
    interactor = providers.Factory(LabelInteractor, service=service, board_service=BoardContainer.service)
```

How i should fix this problem?

Comment: asdasdasdasdasd